# Recovering data from a micro SD card with missing partion after unsafe eject

Tags: disk-utility, partition, data-recovery, sd-card

I am currently stuck trying to recover data from an unsafely ejected 64GB micro SD card that was inside a smartphone.

Windows's `diskpart` utility would not recognize the device at all, so I am trying to recovery from my MacBook on Big Sur.

Using `diskutil`, I at least could find the device and at least one partition (disk4).
[image: Image of Diskpart]

The `diskutil` command could not find the second partition where all the data should be.
Moving over to `fdisk`, I am able to find out that there are still some blocks.

[image]

So, my conclusion is that the MBR might be non working. So, I tried updating it using `fdisk -u /dev/disk4` which will only fail with the following error
[image]

`fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory`

Is someone able to support me?

Comment: Your MBR is not valid. The signature is incorrect. This is one way to verify if there is a valid MBR table. You can ignore the warning message `fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory`. The macOS operating system does not include BIOS boot code for the MBR. With macOS, the command `fdisk -u /dev/disk4` erases any boot code in the MBR.

Comment: Thanks, so my assumption was correct. So how do i proceed?

Comment: Well, you could start by adding the model of the smartphone to your question. BTW, `disk4` is not a partition. Instead, this is the identifier assigned to the SD card. You could try a different SD card. Use the phone to put some data on the card, then try to see if a computer could recognize the format. At least then we would know what to format to look for on the bad card.

Comment: I should also mention that `fsck_exfat -y disk4` (which I assume came from your third party download of exfatprogs) may have damaged the data on the SD card. As I mentioned above, `disk4` is the entire SD card. Although, usually you need to specify `/dev/disk4`. An ExFAT volume is usually in a partition on the SD card.

Comment: One part im not quite sure of is: i've tried to `dd` the whole disk into an image which results in an 128mb image (sizelike the only partition on the sd card). As `dd` copies blockwise  and i'm not quite sure where these blocks are defined from (is it all blocks from the disk or is it rather the blocks which are defined in some header information from the disk?) how are the odds that the flash controller is dead?

the smartphone in question is a low end samsung consumer device, which formats to exfat for 64gb sd cards. I think its the A5

Comment: The drive does not appear to be using a MBR or GUID partition table. I suppose the entire drive could be the ExFAT volume. If this is so, then you partially overwrote the header with zeros when you entered the command `sudo fdisk -u /dev/disk4`.

Comment: that could actually be true. Any idea to proceed? remember, the first time i used `diskutil list` the device had only the 128mb partition.

Comment: You have a point. The size of the drive can not be changed by contents of the data on the drive. Therefore, there must be physical damage somewhere.